# Ad hoc .ipa is not installing using iTune

Tags: ios, itunes, provisioning-profile

I have developed app on iOS sdk 6.1,i code sign it using distribution provisioning profile and certificate,it deployed on device using xcode.Even i can install it using link genrated by [Link](http://www.diawi.com/)

But when im installing the same ipa from iTune,a message box pop up with massege "The app was not installed on the iPhone because it is not compatible with this iPhone! "

Please help me to install the app using iTune

Comment: you need to use provisional certificate with the UDID included with that device

Comment: Bhai i have provisioning certificate,provisioning profile and my device is registered in that provisioning profile.
That is not concern the concern is same ipa is installing on same device using test flight and Xcode(Debugging) but when i'm installing the same ipa one same device using itune its generating error.

Comment: I am in the same @wall-naqvi, did you solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

This message what you got, its because the device is not registered into the provisioning profile. Every devices's UDID must be registered into your Distribution Ad-Hoc provisionin profile.

Step by Step:

- Register all devices into your profile.
- Make a Discitribution Ad-Hoc profile on apple's developer page with the right bundle ID, and check all devices which you want.
- download this profile, and add to Xcode
- Go to product => archive and after distribute
- in discribute chose Ad-Hoc distribution, and I recommend you to save the IPA file to the desktop.
- now you got the Ipa file, double click on it
- iTunes will open, and there click on the phone what you want to synchronize, and under applications you will see your App.
- Click on the "Install" button next to your App
- next syncronize your iPhone, and your app will be installed successfully

Comment: My device is registered,even i have installed the same ipa in same device using test flight but i'm not able to install the same ipa on same device using itune